# how can I get the value from programmatically radio button/check box?

Tags: android

I have a form that the question comes from web service (maybe have check boxes or text field or radio button-made programmatic-ally ) and send the value to the local database.
The first part (call the web service and showing them) is correct but the second part (getting the values) is not!
how can I get the value from programmatic-ally radio button/check box ?
(the important part is i have two "FOR" for radio button or check boxes)

I do not know how can i get the value!??!??!
this is my code, made question!
PLZ help me.

```
for (int i = 0; i < output2.length; i++) {
if (output2[i].contains("#")) {
part1 = output2[i].split("#");
int i2 = 0;
do {

// Question Id ->part1[0]
// FK_MASTERNAZAR ->partinfo_id[0]
// Tilte ->part1[1]

TextView tv2 = new TextView(page2.this);
tv2.setId(i2);
tv2.setText(part1[1]);
tv2.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
lmain2.addView(tv2);

// Answers ->part1[2]
// Type ->part1[3]

switch (Integer.valueOf(part1[3])) {

case 1:
// single selection
part2 = part1[2].split(",");
radioGroup1 = new RadioGroup(page2.this);
radioGroup1.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
radioGroup1.setOrientation(RadioGroup.HORIZONTAL);

for (int i3 = 0; i3 < part2.length; i3++) {
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RadioGroup.LayoutParams(
RadioGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
RadioGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
rb6 = new RadioButton(page2.this);
rb6.setId(i3);
rb6.setText(part2[i3]);
rb6.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
radioGroup1.addView(rb6, 0, layoutParams);
}
lmain2.addView(radioGroup1);
break;

case 2:
et_Num = new EditText(page2.this);
et_Num.setId(i2);
et_Num.setHint("insert your answer…");
et_Num.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED);
lmain2.addView(et_Num);
break;

case 3:
// multi selection
part2 = part1[2].split(",");
LinearLayout lcheck = new LinearLayout(page2.this);
lcheck.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
lcheck.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
for (int i3 = 0; i3 < part2.length; i3++) {

ch6 = new CheckBox(page2.this);
ch6.setId(i3);
ch6.setText(part2[i3]);
ch6.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
lcheck.addView(ch6);
lmain2.addView(lcheck);
break;

}

// T ->part2[4]
// insert line
TextView tv6 = new TextView(page2.this);
tv6.setId(i2);
tv6.setText("**********");
tv6.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
tv6.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#33B5E5"));
lmain2.addView(tv6);

Question_Id = Integer.valueOf(part1[0]);
Integer qtype = Integer.valueOf(part1[4]);

// copy FormQuestion web service to the database
database = new MySQLiteHelper(getApplicationContext());
FormQuestionClass formquestionclass = new FormQuestionClass(
Question_Id, Fk_masternazar, part1[2], part1[3], qtype);
database.InsertQuestion(formquestionclass);
database.close();
// end insertting to db.

} while (i2 == part1.length);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the added controls as fields instead of local variables.

That way you can check later on for null, and if they're not null, use

```
RadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()
EditText.getText()
```